# Elasticsearch 8.6 _geo_distance sorting throws error

Tags: elasticsearch

today I would like to add geo based sorting to my query.
I use Elastic (8.6) Enterprise Search / App Search.

My request body:

```json
{
  "query": "",
  "filters": {
    "location": {
      "center": "51.071646,6.3195429",
      "distance": 500,
      "unit": "km"
    }
  },
  "sort": [
    {
      "_geo_distance": {
        "location": [
          51.071646,
          6.3195429
        ],
        "order": "asc",
        "mode": "min",
        "distance_type": "plane",
        "ignore_unmapped": true
      }
    }
  ],
  "page": {
    "size": 20,
    "current": 1
  }
}
```

... and I get the following response body:

```json
{
  "errors": [
    "Sort contains invalid field: _geo_distance"
  ]
}
```

My document field *location* is set to *geolocation* in schema.

Can anyone give me a hint about what I fundamentally do wrong here?

Without that '*sort*' property the search performs as intended, but I would like to have the distances in relation to the requested location in the response, too.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

For those facing similar situation, I applied the wrong syntax!
As I am in *Elastic **App** Search*, it has to be

```json
{
  "query": "",
  "filters": {
    "location": {
      "center": "51.071646,6.3195429",
      "distance": 500,
      "unit": "km"
    }
  },
  "sort": [
    {
      "location": {
        "center": "51.071646,6.3195429",
        "order": "asc"
      }
    }
  ],
  "page": {
    "size": 20,
    "current": 1
  }
}
```